# My first Physics Engine C++

Tags: c++, simulation, physics

I have made my first physics engine for simulating circles in a plane.
Let me know what you think about it.

```
//main file
#include "col_resolver.cpp"   // collision detector
#include<windows.h>
int main()
{
    int n=0,t=0;                   // number of bodies(n) and t is the number of instants we are going //to simulate
    int x=0;                   //misclaneous use
    cin>>n>>t;
    body B[n];                //array of bodies we are dealing with
    for(int h=0;h<n;++h)    //for loop to input data
    {
        cin>>B[h].pos.i>>B[h].pos.j>>B[h].vel.i>>B[h].vel.j>>B[h].r>>B[h].m;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;++i)      //for loop to simulate t times
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j)    //for loop to update position of bodies in next instant of time
        {
            pos_update(B[j]);
        }
        for(int k=0;k<n;++k)   //for loop to check for collisions
        {
            for(int l=(k+1);l<n;++l) //nested for to detect collisions
            {
                x=col_checker(B[k],B[l]);
                if(x==1)
                {
                    col_res(B[k],B[l]);              //resolving collisions
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<"\n instant "<<i+1;
        for(int m=0;m<n;++m)
        {
            cout<<"\n position of body "<<m+1<<"\n"<<B[m].pos.i<<" "<<B[m].pos.j;   //giving output for each body
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
//collision resolver
#include"collision_detector.cpp"
using namespace std;
void col_res(body& A, body& B);      //function to resolve collision
/*int main()                     //MAIN FUNCTION FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSE
{

}*/
void col_res(body& A,body& B)
{   
    vec ua,ub,va,vb;                          //initial and final velocities of A and B in the rotated coordinate system
    float tan,sin,cos;               //variables to hold sin cos and tan values for the angle through which we rotate our axis
    if(A.pos.j==B.pos.j)
    {
        sin=0;
        cos=1;
    }
    else if(A.pos.i==B.pos.i)
    {
        sin=1;
        cos=0;
    }
    else
    {
        tan=(A.pos.j-B.pos.j)/(A.pos.i-B.pos.i);   // tan calculation by slope method
        sin=tan/(sqrt(1+(tan*tan)));
        cos=sin/tan;
    }
    //we are now rotating our axes to make the line through centre of the bodies the x axis
    ua.i=(A.vel.i*cos)+(A.vel.j*sin);
    ua.j=(A.vel.j*cos)-(A.vel.i*sin);                       //components in rotated system
    ub.i=(B.vel.i*cos)+(B.vel.j*sin);
    ub.j=(B.vel.j*cos)-(B.vel.i*sin);
    va.j=ua.j;                                //collision is along x axis
    vb.j=ub.j;
    va.i=((ua.i*(A.m-B.m))+(2*B.m*ub.i))/(A.m+B.m);  //resolving collision along new x axis
    vb.i=((ub.i*(B.m-A.m))+(2*A.m*ua.i))/(A.m+B.m);
    // now we will convert va and vb back to original coordinate system
    A.vel.i=(va.i*cos)-(va.j*sin);
    B.vel.i=(vb.i*cos)-(vb.j*sin);
    A.vel.j=(va.i*sin)+(va.j*cos);
    B.vel.j=(vb.i*sin)+(vb.j*cos);
}
```

---

```
//collision detector
#include "kinematics.cpp"
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int col_checker(body, body);        //function to check if 2 bodies are colliding
/*int main()                            //MAIN FUNCTION FOR DEBUGGING
{
    body A,B;
    int a;
    cin>>A.pos.i>>A.pos.j>>B.pos.i>>B.pos.j>>A.r>>B.r;
    a=col_checker(A,B);
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}*/
int col_checker(body A, body B)
{
    int a;                                 // a is 1 if there is collision and 0 if no collision
    if(sqrt(((A.pos.i-B.pos.i)*(A.pos.i-B.pos.i))+((A.pos.j-B.pos.j)*(A.pos.j-B.pos.j)))<=(A.r+B.r))     //applying distance formula
    {
        a=1;
    }
    else
    {
        a=0;
    }
    return a;
}
```

---

```
//kinematics simulator
#include "vectors.cpp"        // vector manager file included
struct body               //structure for velocity and position of a rigid circular body
{
    vec pos,vel;       // position of centre of circle and velocity vector
    float r,m;              //radius of circular body  m for mass
};
void pos_update(body&); // function for updating the postion by taking body structure as argument
/*int main()                                   
{                                                   //MAIN FUNCTION FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSE
    body a;
    cin>>a.pos.i>>a.pos.j>>a.vel.i>>a.vel.j;  // taking everyting in input
    a=pos_update(a);                           // updating position
    cout<<a.pos.i<<" "<<a.pos.j;          //giving new position as output
    return 0;   
}*/
void pos_update(body& x)           // taking position and velocities as arguments
{
    x.pos=addition(x.pos,x.vel);           // adding the 2 vectors because we are considering for unit time
}
```

---

```
// vector manager
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
struct vec                  // structure for storing a 2d vector   
{
    float i,j,k;     // 3 components,i,j and k       k component is included to store magnitude of torque
};
vec addition(vec,vec);      //addition of 2 vectors
vec subtraction(vec,vec) ;    //subtraction of 2 vectors
vec scalarmultiply(float,vec);  // multiplying a scalar and vector
float dotproduct(vec,vec)    ;     //dot product of 2 vectors
vec crossproduct(vec,vec)  ;    //cross product of 2 vectors
float mag(vec);               //magnitude of vector
/*int main()
{
    vec a,b,c;
    int d;
    char o;             //operation to be performed
    cin>>o;
    switch(o)
    {
    case 'a':        //addion case
        cin>>a.i>>a.j>>b.i>>b.j;      // taking inout in sequence
        c=addition(a,b);                //performing action
        cout<<c.i<<" "<<c.j;          // output
        break;
    case 's':             // subtraction case
        cin>>a.i>>a.j>>b.i>>b.j;      // taking inout in sequence
        c=subtraction(a,b);
        cout<<c.i<<" "<<c.j;
        break;
    case 'm':                 //scalar multiply
        cin>>d>>b.i>>b.j;
        c=scalarmultiply(d,b);                                                   //MAIN FUNCTION FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSE
        cout<<c.i<<" "<<c.j;          // output
        break;
    case 'd':                        //dotproduct
        cin>>a.i>>a.j>>b.i>>b.j;      // taking inout in sequence
        d=dotproduct(a,b);
        cout<<d;
        break;
    case 'c' :            //crossproduct
        cin>>a.i>>a.j>>b.i>>b.j;      // taking inout in sequence
        c=crossproduct(a,b);
        cout<<c.k;
        break;
    }
    return 0;       
}*/
vec addition(vec a,vec b)          //addition function
{
    vec c;                           //final vector
    c.i=a.i+b.i;                    // adding 'i' components
    c.j=a.j+b.j;                 // adding 'j' components
    return c;                    // returning final vector
}
vec subtraction(vec a,vec b)           //subtraction function
{
    vec c;
    c.i=a.i-b.i;                  //subtracting 'i' components
    c.j=a.j-b.j;                    //subtracting 'j' components
    return c;                    //returning final vector
}
vec scalarmultiply(float a, vec b)       // multiplying vector by a scalar    a is scalar and b is vector
{
    vec c;
    c.i=a*b.i;                       //formula applied
    c.j=a*b.j;
    return c;
}
float dotproduct(vec a,vec b)              //scalar product of 2 vectors, result is a scalar
{
    float c;                                  // resultant scalar
    c=(a.i*b.i)+(a.j*b.j);      // application of formula       
    return c;
}
vec crossproduct(vec a,vec b)      //vector product of 2 products
{
    vec c;
    c.i=0;             // i and j components are 0 as cross product is perpendicular to the plane containing the original vectors
    c.j=0;
    c.k=(a.i*b.j)-(a.j*b.i); //applying formula
    return c;
}
float mag(vec a)
{
    float m;
    m=sqrt((a.i*a.i)+(a.j*a.j));
    return m;
}
```

Comment: All in all that looks more like c code than c++.

Comment: Most of your comments are devoid of sense or just restate the code. In other words, they are worse than useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holy moly, there is some really mean stuff in here.

To reiterate the obvious that has already been mentioned

1. Do not include headers
2. Do no use namespace std;
3. Encapsulate your data
4. Lines are cheap so use it. Stuff like `float i,j,k;` is a bad practice.
5. Characters are cheap so use them. Names like `float i,j,k;` are terrible because noone that read some code knows what it is. If you name the variable `torque` rather than `k` it is not necessary to write a comment about it and the user sees the purpose whenever the variable is in the code.
6. Have a look at the standard constructs like operators.

For example you should create a class for your vector:

```
class myVector {
public:    
    // Default to the standard constructors
    myVector() = default;
    myVector(const myVector&) = default;
    myVector(myVector&&) = default;

    // Defaulting to the standard assignment operators
    myVector& operator=(const myVector&) = default;
    myVector& operator=(myVector&&) = default;

    ~myVector() = default;

    // create the appropriate operators for mathematical operations
    // Addition with a new vector
    myVector operator+(const myVector& otherVec) {
        myVector temp;
        temp.x_coordinate = x_coordinate + otherVec.x_coordinate;
        temp.y_coordinate = y_coordinate + otherVec.y_coordinate;
        return temp;
    }

    // In place addition
    myVector& operator+=(const myVector& otherVec) {
        x_coordinate += otherVec.x_coordinate;
        y_coordinate += otherVec.y_coordinate;
        return *this;
    }

    // Here come the other operations
private:
    double x_coordinate;
    double y_coordinate;
    double torque;
}
```

Similarly you should create a class for your body

```
//kinematics simulator
#include "myVector.h"

//structure for velocity and position of a rigid circular body
class myBody {
public:
    myBody() = default;
    myBody(const myBody&) = default;
    myBody(myBody &&) = default;

    // Defaulting to the standard assignment operators
    myBody& operator=(const myBody&) = default;
    myBody& operator=(myBody&&) = default;

    void updatePosition();
    void updateVelocity();

private:
    myVector pos;           // Position on the 2D map
    myVector vel;           // Velocity
    double r;               // Physical radiums of the body
    double m;               // Mass of the body
};
```

Comment: Naturally, you wouldn't explicitly default any function without good reason...

Comment: For complex classes obviously not, but for one that holds 3 doulbe, zero initialization is kind of save. Clearly there should also be a constructor that takes values

Comment: "do not include headers" I guess you meant source files

Comment: OOps you are obviously right

Answer (score 5):

## 1. Never ever ...

... do this:

> ```
> #include "col_resolver.cpp"
> ```

`cpp` files aren't intended to be included, but to be compiled separately and linked with your `main.cpp`.

Separate out function declarations to header files instead, include these, and provide the implementation in translation units (`.cpp` files).
I'd expect you would get problems with linking, if those sources are managed in a project file of your IDE.

## 2. Don't use `using namespace std;`

While that would work in your particular case, it's considered bad practice. Especially when you move out your code to separate header files.

See more details here please:

[Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

## 3. Use classes to encapsulate your data

Stuff like that

> ```
> struct body               //structure for velocity and position of a rigid circular body
> {
>     vec pos,vel;       // position of centre of circle and velocity vector
>     float r,m;              //radius of circular body  m for mass
> };
> void pos_update(body&); // function for updating the postion by taking body structure as argument
>
> // ...
>
> void pos_update(body& x)           // taking position and velocities as arguments
> {
>     x.pos=addition(x.pos,x.vel);           // adding the 2 vectors because we are considering for unit time
> }
> ```

should be placed in a class with appropriate member functions instead:

```
class body
{
    vec pos,vel;       // position of centre of circle and velocity vector
    float r,m;              //radius of circular body  m for mass
public:
    void pos_update(); // function for updating the postion by taking body structure as argument
};

// ...

void body::pos_update()           // taking position and velocities as arguments
{
    pos=addition(pos,vel);           // adding the 2 vectors because we are considering for unit time
}
```

## 4. Don't comment the obvious

The comment here (and in other places)

> ```
>     x.pos=addition(x.pos,x.vel);           // adding the 2 vectors because
> ```

is useless. It's quite ovious what that line of code does.

Rather use comments to document design decisions, that aren't obvious for future readers/maintainers of your code.

---

## Conclusion

> Let me know what you think about it.

All in all I believe that your implementation isn't acceptable and valid c++ code.
It looks more like c code that is *"furnished up"* with some basic c++ standard library functionality.

Though even with the c language you would obviously miss the point of `#include` statements, and separating declaration done in header files, and definition provided in translation units which will be stiched together in the linking proces.

The best advice I can give is to pick a book from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start to learn the basics.
An overworked c++ style code would look fairly different from what you've been presenting here.

Comment: No matther who writes a C++ review, I always read the same sentence there: _don't use using namespace std;_ I think it should be automatically posted as soon as you add the [tag:c++] tag ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t I've been copying that part from one of my earlier answers of course ;-)

Comment: Also, use an existing, well tested linear algebra library like "eigen" instead of writing out all the operations manually.